# In processing, is there a property akin to zorder in matplotlib?

Tags: processing

I have many circles positioned randomly in my processing program. Each one is initiated as so:

```
ellipse(x, y, radius, radius);
```

I was wondering if I could somehow specify an z-index value for each circle. Circles of higher z-indices display over those of lower ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>I cannot test this right now but I believe you should look at the `fill()` method. The fourth parameter in this function specifies opacity (AKA alpha transparency). It is described at [Processing.org/learning/color](http://processing.org/learning/color/).</s>

---

**EDIT:**  This [thread](http://processing.org/discourse/yabb2/YaBB.pl?num=1269266784) on drawing order seems to ask the same question as yours. Playing around with the image transparency is suggested, but it seems like a better answer is to utilize the [Processing Layar Library](http://nootropicdesign.com/processing-layers/). Here are [some examples](http://nootropicdesign.com/processing-layers/#examples) - the first one appears to be along the lines of your question.

Quoting the [Advanced](http://nootropicdesign.com/processing-layers/#advanced) section of the Layers examples:

> **Dynamically Adding, Removing, or Reordering Layers**
>
> It is possible to dynamically add, remove, or reorder layers during a
> sketch's execution, but great care should be taken when doing so. The
> list of layers managed by the AppletLayers object can be manipulated
> by obtaining a ListIterator object. The semantics of how a list can be
> manipulated via an iterator should be studied carefully by reading the
> [Javadoc for java.util.ListIterator](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html). The reason it is difficult to
> manipulate a list during sketch execution is because the list of
> layers is being iterated through in order to render them. The best
> place to manipulate the list of layers is in the main sketch's draw()
> method and not in a layer's draw() method or in mouse or keyboard
> event processing.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to keep track of your ellipses using an array or a list, so you'd have two steps:

1. Create a basic class to keep track of your specialized ellipse properties(x,y,w,h, but also zIndex and any extra data the object will hold)
2. Create an array/arraylist which can be sorted based on zIndex.

Here's an example using a typed [ArrayList](http://processing.org/reference/ArrayList.html):

```
ArrayList<Ellipse> ellipses = new ArrayList<Ellipse>();

void setup(){
  size(400,400,P2D);
  smooth();
  fill(192,0,0,192);
  reset();
}
void reset(){
  ellipses.clear();
  for(int i = 0 ; i < 40; i++){
    float radius = random(5,25);
    Ellipse e = new Ellipse(i*10,random(20,380),radius,radius,i);
    ellipses.add(i,e);
  }
}
void draw(){
  background(255);
  for(Ellipse e : ellipses) e.draw();
}
void keyPressed(){
  reset();
}
class Ellipse{
  float x,y,w,h;
  int zIndex;
  Ellipse(float ax,float ay,float aw,float ah,int az){
    x = ax;
    y = ay;
    w = aw;
    h = ah;
    zIndex = az;
  }
  void draw(){
    ellipse(x,y,w,h);
  }
}
```

Notice that ArrayLists are quite flexible and you can add an element at what index you need easily.

If you want to use arrays, you need make sure you can sort the array based on the property you choose, so you need to implement the [Comparable interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html):

```
int numEllipses = 40;
Ellipse[] ellipses = new Ellipse[numEllipses];//this will store original/unsorted data
Ellipse[] ellipsesSorted = new Ellipse[numEllipses];//this will store the sorted data

void setup(){
  size(400,400,P2D);
  smooth();
  fill(192,0,0,192);
  reset();
}
void reset(){
  for(int i = 0 ; i < numEllipses; i++){
    float radius = random(5,25);
    int index = (int)random(0,numEllipses);
    Ellipse e = new Ellipse(i*10,random(20,380),radius,radius,index);
    ellipses[i] = e;
  }
  //copy original data into an array to be sorted
  arrayCopy(ellipses, ellipsesSorted);
  //sort the array - uses the compareTo method behind the scenes
  Arrays.sort(ellipsesSorted);
}
void draw(){
  background(255);
  for(Ellipse e : ellipsesSorted) e.draw();
}
void keyPressed(){
  reset();
}
class Ellipse implements Comparable<Ellipse>{
  float x,y,w,h;
  int zIndex;
  Ellipse(float ax,float ay,float aw,float ah,int az){
    x = ax;
    y = ay;
    w = aw;
    h = ah;
    zIndex = az;
  }
  void draw(){
    ellipse(x,y,w,h);
  }
  int compareTo(Ellipse e)
  {
    if(e.zIndex > this.zIndex) return 1;
    else if(e.zIndex < this.zIndex) return -1;
    else return 0;
  }
  String toString(){
    return "z index: "+zIndex;
  }
}
```